# SurfaceView in ScrollView under 4.1

Tags: android, scrollview, surfaceview

Here is the problem.
For performance reasons, I choose to use a SurfaceView to draw a table-like form, and because this stuff is full of data I use a ScrollView as SurfaceView parent.

Happy to see it works fine on my personal development-dedicated phone (HTC Desire HD 2.3.7), I tried to test it on one of my company development-dedicated phone (Google Nexus S 4.1.?) and then on my personal phone (HTC One X 4.1.1).

Something went wrong on those two last ones, my SurfaceView just turned black after some ~80px scroll and turned back to what it should look like when I scrolled back under this ~80px (depends on screen size).

Trying to avoid this blackout, I tested under some emulators...

From 2.2 (customer's wish) to 4.0.4, it works just great.

The joke is, under 4.2... it works too!

**Definitely, that is only under 4.1.x that the SurfaceView turns black!**

Here is my SurfaceView code, that I just copied from the sample you can find [here](http://android-er.blogspot.fr/2010/05/android-surfaceview.html).

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView
{
    public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        // I use another SurfaceView behind to draw a grid
        // that is scroll independent with a white background
        this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        // Same reason here
        this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        this.getHolder().setSizeFromLayout();
        // Tried without this line and with "software" and "none" types too
        // and hardware acceleration on application and activity
        this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawSomething()...
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);

        this.thread = new MySurfaceViewThread(this.getHolder(), this);
        this.thread.setRunning(true);
        this.thread.run();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        this.thread.setRunning(false);
        boolean retry = true;
        while(retry)
        {
            try
            {
                this.thread.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                Log.v(TAG, exception.getClass().getName(), exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snippet could be an answer

```
if(VERSION.SDK_INT != VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
{
    this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
}
```

But the problem with doing this is that the background gets black.

I have to draw the grid I drawn in the "background" SurfaceView on this one too for this specific android version.

That is not a good solution, because drawing that grid in this SurfaceView breaks the smoothness of the scroll and the pinch-to-zoom.